# How to execute the JQuery function after the JSON function sends success?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2

I use struts2-jquery-plugin and struts2-json-plugin.

My problem is that **the jQuery function is executed before the action function in my action class**.

1) The jQuery function defined on my JSP page is called by **onchange=verifyChosenLanguage(this.value)**.

2) The action function which is defined in my action class LanguagesForm.java is **loadLanguages**, it is called by **onChangeTopics="reloadFrameworks"**.

3) In LanguagesFormAction.java I defined a boolean variable FrameworksExist. So if the DAO function tell me that it exist a framework for the chosen language I set **FrameworksExist=true**, otherwise to false. And so in the jQuery function I test if FrameworksExist==true or FrameworksExist==false.

But unfortunately what I noticed is that the event **onchange is called before that loadLanguages sends "success". And so my function still finds that FrameworksExist==false.**

How can I do for that my jQuery function get executed after the returned string (success) of the action function triggered by the select?

The jQuery function :

```
function verifyChosenLanguage(value){
  var someText = '<s:property value="FrameworksExist"/>';
  alert(" FrameworksExist = "+someText+"what"); // this gives me always "false"
}
```

The double selects of the form :

```
<s:url id="remoteurl1" action="loadLanguages"/>
<sj:select 
  onchange="verifyChosenLanguage(this.value)"                   
  href="%{remoteurl1}"                          
  label="Category "                     
  id="IdChosenLanguage"                 
  name="IdChosenLanguage"   
  onChangeTopics="reloadFrameworks"         
  list="languages"                      
  listKey="lang_id"             
  listValue="lang_name"                     
  emptyOption="false"                           
  headerKey="None"                          
  headerValue="Select a language"
/> 

<s:url id="remoteurl2" action="loadLanguages"/> 
<sj:select                                      
  href="%{remoteurl2}"
  label="Framework "                        
  id="IdChosenFramework"
  name="IdChosenFramework"                  
  formIds="formLanguages"           
  reloadTopics="reloadFrameworks"                   
  list="frameworks" 
  listKey="frame_id"                        
  listValue="frame_name"                    
  emptyOption="false"                           
  headerKey="None"                          
  headerValue="Select a Framework"
/>
```

LanguagesFormAction.java :

```
@Actions( {
  @Action(value = "/loadLanguages", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", type = "json")
  })
})
public String loadLanguages(){

  // instructions
  if ( (languageDAO.countFrameworks(Long.valueOf(IdChosenLanguage)!=0){
    FrameworksExist=true;
  }
  else{
    FrameworksExist=false;
  }
  // instructions
  return "success";
}
public String getJSON()
{
   return loadLanguages();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for  `FrameworksExist` in your jQuery function is evaluated when your JSP loads.  Remember that you have used a regular struts2 property tag and it cannot magically change or reload its value based on an ajax call to an action.

```
function verifyChosenLanguage(value){
  var someText = '<s:property value="FrameworksExist"/>'; // <-- Evaluated on first load of your JSP
  alert(" FrameworksExist = "+someText+"what"); // Does not change based on ajax calls      
}
```

The `loadLanguages` action only changes the values of your `<sj:select>` items because that is all that it applies to.  Calling `loadLanguages` as you have it **does not update ALL values on your JSP page**.

EDIT:

If you want to get the value of `FrameworkExists` from your select input interaction, you can subscribe to the appropriate topics by doing something like this:

```
$.subscribe('topicName', function(event,data) {
    // Parse for and prcess your FrameworkExists data here as you wish.
});
```

You can see the example for *Remote Link with JSON Result* at the [demo site](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

Comment: So how can I do to get the value of FrameworksExist after that the action function sends success?? Thank you!

Comment: @user1459961 I've added to the answer above to give you a starting point.